Secret military program to train people for missions(?)
It was about a group of test subjects that were signing up for drug testing to get money.  However, it was secretly a program by the military to train people for something (suicide missions?) and then they were placed in a white room and had to escape.  There were secret messages on the room that they used blood to reveal.  It was pretty weird, but I can't remember the name of it.  I thought someone famous was in it.
Can anyone identify this movie?
